# JavaScript API - how to do it in PHP (for Google News)

Tags: php, javascript, api

Google News has API, described here:
http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/v1/index.html

But it is a JavaScript API (client side). I would like to run Google News search once a day for a fixed phrase, automatically, on a server and integrate the results into my database (server side, using PHP).

Could anyone suggest how to deal with this, I mean on Google API side? I made a solution using PHP simple_html_dom class, which is parsing raw html and extracting elements like news title, body etc. But now I think it is not a professional solution, because if Google changes anything within the structure of their html, my code will break.

So maybe there is a trick, how to use a JavaScript API in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the PHP example for Google News Search API.

http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/v1/jsondevguide.html#json_snippets_php

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the documentation for the JavaScript API, it is just a wrapper around the [JSON API](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/v1/jsondevguide.html). Use the documentation for that instead. PHP can handle [JSON](http://php.net/json) and [HTTP](http://php.net/curl)